# Force https traffic on Bitnami lightsail aws

Tags: https, apache2, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I want to make sure I get this right before messing anything up.
According to `[bitnami docs found here][1]` to force HTTPS I should go to this file:

```
/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf
```

When I get here the current file has this for virutal host 80:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
  <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
 Require all granted
</IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  # Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

After I add the code it's telling me to update, it would look like this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
  <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
 Require all granted
</IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  # Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

Is this correct?
[1]: https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/apps/wordpress/administration/force-https-apache/

Comment: That looks correct, yes.

Comment: I added that code but the redirect does not work. It worked for you?